# Getting line number of code

Tags: c#, debugging, testing

Within the code I'm responsible for, I have a few 'throw new Exception()' methods flying around.

The issue is, the `catch` is not always in the best place or even in the same class. This means when I catch an error, I don't know where the `throw` originated or even if I do, there could be hundreds/thousands of lines of code in each class.

So, within the `throw` message, for debugging, it may be useful to state the Class Name, Project Name, Method Name and the line number for easier navigation. The line number is tricky. I can't hard code it because as soon as I amend the code it's unlikely to remain on the same line.

So, my 2 questions are
1) Do we like this idea or think no, there are better approaches!
2) Any ideas how to get the line number?

Comment: This info is usually available in the stack trace.

Comment: Having thousands of lines in a single class is not a good idea.

Comment: To jump to the exact line in visual studio, use the keyboard shortcut ctrl+g

Comment: I don't know if what you want is possible; but it sounds like the Stack Trace already gives you almost exactly the same thing.  Only better, because it shows the call order leading up to the exception - not just the line.  (Unless I'm misunderstanding you, in that case - sorry)

Comment: link to a post about this:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a58dc2a0-0612-407b-8cbe-10f1784ba85a/

Comment: @Jeremy Ah - it's right at the bottom of the stack trace. Thank you

Comment: @unholysampler - I never said it was my code   :)  I've 'inherited' from some one who should not have been doing this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered looking at the StackTrace information found under System.Diagnostics? An example can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you include the **debugging symbols (.pdb)** files, in the same directory as the `.dll` or `.exe`, it should load them automatically and provide the line number in the `exception.StackTrace`.

To build the symbols, in your **release** build settings, under **Advanced Build Settings**, turn **Debug Info** to **Full**

[image: Advanced Build Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `System.Diagnostics.StackFrame` class for grabbing line numbers. I believe the method `GetFileLineNumber` may help you out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe

Answer (score 0):

This info is usually available in the stack trace - By Jeremy (see my comments).

Sorry, not sure how to mark a comment as the right answer!?

Comment: Can't unless he makes it an answer

Answer (score 0):

Line numbers do not show up in code compiled in Release mode.  If this is an in-house application you and you *really* want the line numbers you could always deploy the code compiled in Debug mode and then deploy the PDB's with the assemblies.  But there is a performance cost involved in this as well so this is not always the best approach. I am not sure of any better approach at this point though.

If I remember correctly, the Roslyn project gives us a better way to get line numbers but not familiar enough with it to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the line number of a caller using C# 5.0 feature combined with default parameters.  So instead of constructing and throwing the exception directly, make a method that constructs your exception.

```
Exception CreateMyException(
    [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "", 
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
{
   return new Exception(string.Format("Exception thrown from line {0} in member {1} in file {2}",
       lineNumber, memberName, filePath));
}
```

...elsewhere in your code...

```
throw CreateMyException();  // compiler injects current values for defaulted arguments.
```